# How to get email id from company page using JSOUP and regex

Tags: regex, email, jsoup

I am trying to get email id and link from the company page http://customercarecontacts.com/contact-infosys-phone-address-of-infosys-offices/

I was succeded to get link but i am not getting the email. I have tried many ways but failed. Here is the code I am trying

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JSoupTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://customercarecontacts.com/contact-infosys-phone-address-of-infosys-offices/").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(5000).get();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(doc.text());
    Set<String> emails = new HashSet<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        emails.add(matcher.group());
    }

    Set<String> links = new HashSet<String>();

    Elements elements = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element e : elements) {
        links.add(e.attr("href"));
    }

    System.out.println("emails : "+emails);
    System.out.println("links : "+links);

}

}
```

Can anyone suggest the way or solution to get email.

Comment: If you see the page source, you will see `askus (at) infosys.com (queries)<br />
<a class="__cf_email__" href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" data-cfemail="600a0f021320090e060f1319134e030f0d">[email&#160;protected]</a>` - your pattern does not match. You won't be able to get the second email and to get the first, you need to use `"[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+(?:@|\\s*\\(at\\)\\s*)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+"`

Comment: I am getting debug when I added the pattern that you have sent . That is also not working @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: That is because you copied/pasted it from the comment, SO inserts weird chars into comments. [It is working well](https://regex101.com/r/JkqWlU/1). Anyway, you can't get protected emails, so there is no solution to your question.

Comment: I want this email : jobs@infosys.com and not this email : askus (at) infosys.com

Comment: I said that one was protected, there is no way to get it.

Comment: How do we know that email was protected one ? are you saying that as I am not getting that email

Comment: I suspect `doc.text()` fetches the same text as I see when clicking to see the Web page source HTML in the browser. I see `<a class="__cf_email__" href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" data-cfemail="600a0f021320090e060f1319134e030f0d">[email&#16‌​0;protected]</a>` there. *There is no `jobs@infosys.com` in the text*, thus, you can't get it.

Comment: @bunnysunny the email that you see in the view is generated by javascript. when you get html document programatically, it doesn't execute javascript. Therefore, the email you are referring to is not renderred. regex can not get you that email address.

Comment: okay thank you @Maverick_Mrt

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+(@\\w+|\\s*\\(at\\)\\s*\\w+)\\.[a-zA-Z]+
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/EKy2FF/1)

> Sample Java Code

```
final String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+(@\\w+|\\s*\\(at\\)\\s*\\w+)\\.[a-zA-Z]+";
final String string = "df\n"
     + "askus (at) infosys.com (queries)<br />\n"
     + "asdfasdf\n"
     + "asdfasdf\n"
     + "asdf abc@yahoo.com asdfadsf\n"
     + "asdf pqr@google.com a sdfasfd\n\n\n";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me thank you @Maverick . But how to get multiple emails in that page itself  ? I used while loop although I am not getting all the emails

Comment: can you please give some example of email address situated in the page, which i have missed?

Comment: http://customercarecontacts.com/contact-infosys-phone-address-of-infosys-offices/. This is the company page link. I  want this email : jobs@infosys.com and I am getting only this email : askus (at) infosys.com which is unnecessary for me.

Comment: @bunnysunny the email that you see in the view is generated by javascript. when you get html document programatically, it doesn't execute javascript. Therefore, the email you are referring to is not renderred. regex can not get you that email address.